# How to create workflows suitable for distribution in python

Tags: python, workflow, snakemake

We need to create a workflow consisting of commands from multiple packages in a way that, at the end, other members of the institute (who by the way are not computer scientists) to be able to download and use it.

Searching online, there are some packages for creating workflows (https://www.biostars.org/p/91301/) and among them Snakemake (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v3.9.1/snakefiles/deployment.html) seems to be a good candidate for this purpose.

We were wondering whether this is really the best package for this purpose and if there are any better options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a lot on the computer literacy of the used based, and the budget available. Really understand who will be using your software//programs. Everything depends on this and it will reduce the pool of languages to choose from.

Check out this paper too: 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5429012/

Our group chose Snakemake after approx 6 weeks of investigating the landscape (Feb-March 2017)

In terms of just the right amount of ease-of-use, while still allowing for enough customization by experienced coders, Snakemake was just the right fit. A lot if functionality, more than enough. Great cluster integration. Wrappers are really cool, and easy to use. We wanted a bit more granularity and control, so we are actually writing all our own modules (replicating ones currently written in GNU Make).

For distribution, Snakemake has this, which is convenient. 
https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/deployment.html

Snakemake is maintained well in conda (Anaconda.org) as well, which further supports portability. This was a significant issue for me as I run on CentOS5 (Old Operating System). Johannes efforts for backwards compatibility are superb.
https://anaconda.org/bioconda/snakemake

Snakemake leverages python well. Python and R are two languages I would consider relevant in the bio-computational community, so in terms of finding students or hiring those with experience, you're candidate pool is larger. I use python scripts to build modularized pipelines. All my pipeling (dependencies) is written in Snakemake, the execution of my tasks are done in Python (with a little bit of Bash). Solid scaling. Wildcards are can be tricky, but with the power of regular expressions one can expect difficulties.

The author is still very active as well, which was a huge consideration for us, on StackOverflow, BitBucket, and in the Google Groups.

- https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/snakemake
- https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues

Aside from functionality, we also considered moving forward. Snakemake seems to be written by someone who is deeply submerged in the biological community. BDS's author follows a similar mindset. Some of the other languages, the larger ones, are run by company's. Not saying companies are bad, but I think there may be underlying motivational differences.

Other languages we considered were:

1. Nextflow: https://www.nextflow.io/
   It's not that this isn't a great language, the language significantly empowers the coder, however, they as developers decided to invent new terminology, based on the "dataflow programming paradigm". It greatly steepens the learning curve when trying to develop in the language. 
   https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/basic.html#processes-and-channels
2. BigDataScript: https://pcingola.github.io/BigDataScript/bigDataScript_manual.html
   I really enjoyed this language, it more closely resembles the coding languages you learn in school, (Java, C), and it uses a lot of the same terminology. This would have been our second choice, had our group not already had a strong familiarity with GNU Make's coding style we may have ended up using BDS. Also, the author of this language is the author of snpEff.

There are a plethora of other languages. Our group really just ended up examining the three in detail. I have slide-shows (20+ slides in PPTX) on Snakemake and BDS, highlighting the features we valued in each, if interested I can host for you to read. Nothing special, mainly just snippets from reading the manuals of each language.

The biostars link you have we also deeply valued.

This article reflects my feelings between Snakemake and Nextflow: https://jmazz.me/blog/NGS-Workflows

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I would appreciate if you could also provide your slides on this topic in slideshare or send it directly to me: masih.mahmoudi@nig.ac.jp

Comment: Emailed them to you. Enjoy!

Comment: A few notes about Nextflow: a `process` is not a function, it is a reactive dataflow operation (functions can be defined in NF but they are not central in this model). A `channel` is an unbounded asynchronous queue, somehow similar to Go channels. The terminology used reflects the Dataflow programming paradigm on which is based.